# Prove that if $B\setminus C \subseteq \ A^c $ then $A \cap B \subseteq C$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Let A, B and C three sets. Prove that if $B-C$ $\subseteq$ $A^c$then $A \cap B \subseteq C$

Im trying to prove this with sheer logic and not making  use of De Morgans laws etc.

Let $y \in (B-C\space$ $\subseteq$ $A^c)$

$y \in B, y\notin C \subseteq A^c$  -----> $A^c$ is equivalent to $B \cup C$ in the given problem.

$y \in B, y\notin C \subseteq y \in B$ or $y\in C$

Thus I proved that $B \subseteq C$ since $B$is in $B$ or $C$. (or at least I think)

Next I have to prove that $A$ is also a $\subseteq C$ and am unsure how to proceed. If I manage to do this I think I will have proved  $A \cap B \subseteq C$.

Feel free to show how you would do it, if I am completely wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: $B\subseteq C$ is not true. Take $C = \varnothing$ and $A,B$ disjoint.

Comment: De Morgan's laws *are* sheer logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prove that $A\cap B$ is a subset of $C$. At this level, things do not require immense bursts of creativity, or a stream of great ideas. Usually just verifying the definitions is fairly straightforward and short.

So you need to show that if $x\in A\cap B$ then $x\in C$. If $x\in A\cap B$ then $x\in A$ and $x\in B$. Now comes the point to use the assumption, $B-C\subseteq A^c$. The assumption, when unraveling to definitions tells us that if $x\in B$ and $x\notin C$, then $x\notin A$.

Now our assumption is that $x\in B$, since $x\in A$ it is impossible that $x\notin C$, because then $x\notin A$. Therefore $x\in C$, as wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Let x be any element in (A and B). If x is in C, then we have (A and B) is a subset of C. If x is not in C, then since x is in (A and B) we have x is in B and now not in C so it is in (B - C). But (B - C) is a subset of A', so x is in A', which means x is not in A, but this contradicts x belong to A. So x is in C and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite both expressions, by expanding the definitions and simplifying on the element/logic level.

For the first expression, we get
\begin{align}
& B - C \;\subseteq\; A^c \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B - C \;\Rightarrow\; x \in A^c \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;-\;$; definition of $\;^c\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in B \land x \not\in C \;\Rightarrow\; x \not\in A \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"expand $\;p \Rightarrow q\;$ to $\;\lnot p \lor q\;$; DeMorgan on left hand side"} \\
(0) \;\;\; \phantom{\equiv} & \langle \forall x :: x \not\in B \lor x \in C \lor x \not\in A \rangle \\
\end{align}

For the second expression the result is
\begin{align}
& A \cap B \;\subseteq\; C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\subseteq\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \cap B \;\Rightarrow\; x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \land x \in B \;\Rightarrow\; x \in C \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"expand $\;p \Rightarrow q\;$ to $\;\lnot p \lor q\;$; DeMorgan on left hand side"} \\
(1) \;\;\; \phantom{\equiv} & \langle \forall x :: x \not\in A \lor x \not\in B \lor x \in C \rangle \\
\end{align}

Since $(0)$ and $(1)$ are equivalent, this proves the original expressions are also equivalent.

Comment: For open quotation marks use the backquote character, it should do the trick: $``$.

Answer (score 0):

I know the wanted answer would be using "sheer logic" but this can also be helpful for other other viewers. Using De Morgan laws, definitions and premises we need to show that if $x \in A \cap B$ then $x\in C$.

Let $x\in A\cap B$

$\Rightarrow x\in A \land x\in B$

$\Rightarrow x\notin A^C \land x\in B$

$\Rightarrow x\notin B-C \land x\in B$ (because of the premise $B-C \subset A^C$)

$\Rightarrow x\notin B\cap C^C \land x\in B$ (because $B-C=B\cap C^C$)

$\Rightarrow x\in (B\cap C^C)^C \land x\in B$

$\Rightarrow x\in B^C\cup C \land x\in B$ (De Morgan)

$\Rightarrow x\in (B^C\cup C)\cap B$

$\Rightarrow x\in (B^C\cap B)\cup (C\cap B)$ (Distribution)

$\Rightarrow x\in \emptyset \cup (C\cap B)$

$\Rightarrow x\in C\cap B$

$\Rightarrow x\in C$

Answer (score 0):

Supose, for absurd that $A\cap B\not \subset C$, then, $\exists x\in A\cap B$ such that $x\not \in C$. Then, \begin{equation}x\in A\, ,x\in B\text{ and }  x\not \in C \text{  ,         }(\star)   \end{equation} i.e.,  $x\in B\setminus C$. But $x\in B\setminus C\subset A^{\complement}$, then $x\in A^{\complement}$, i.e., $x\not \in A$, a absurd with ($\star$).